# String to Class Name in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string

```
var className = "HomeViewController"
```

I would like to convert `"HomeViewController"` to `HomeViewController`.

I'm using this for type casting. Here's an example of how I would use this.

```
let homeViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeView") as! className // obviously it wouldn't be className but HomeViewController
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift has strict, static typing! What you're trying to do is exactly what Swift does not want you to do. It is directly opposed to the design and spirit of Swift. You should ask yourself *why* you think you need to do it; if you can provide a good answer, maybe you should stick with Objective-C.

Points to note:

- You can't use the `as` operator with anything but a literal type; you would have to use `unsafeBitCast` instead:

  ```
  class ViewController : UIViewController {
      let greeting = "howdy"
  }
  let uvc : UIViewController = ViewController()
  let whattype = ViewController.self
  let vc = unsafeBitCast(uvc, whattype)
  vc.greeting // "howdy"
  ```
- Swift won't let you convert from a string name to a type; you'll need to start with an actual type, as above, or get Cocoa to help you with `NSClassFromString`. But then in the latter case, I don't see how you'd get from there to the use of `unsafeBitCast`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think: What does an `as!` cast mean, really?

1. At compile-time, the expression `a as! B` has compile-time type `B`, which then makes the compiler allows you to perform operations you can do with type `B` to the whole expression, which you couldn't do with whatever type `a` was.
2. At runtime, it checks the runtime value of whatever `a` evaluates to, and if it is not a subtype of `B`, it throws a runtime error.

Now, you want to "cast" (as!) to a type that is only known at runtime.

#1 obviously doesn't make sense for this, because the compile-time type of an expression obviously cannot depend on a type not known at compile time.

#2 (runtime check) still can be done with a type only known at runtime. You can do this manually yourself, by using `(a as AnyObject).isKindOfClass(...)` with a runtime type (which you could have gotten using `NSClassFromString`, etc.), and then if it fails, you can then throw an error.